# Find the index of the range R

Tags: r, vector, indexing, match

I am trying to build a function that given a vector of numbers and a vector limits it finds the range that the elements of the first vector belongs.

If i have a vector that looks like this one

```
numbers<-c(3,10,4,6,1)
```

and a vector of limits such as

```
limits<-c(2,5,7,12)
```

the result would be

```
1,3,1,2,NA
```

I have tried with `which` or `match` but no much luck so far.

Comment: Try `findInterval(numbers, limits)`

Comment: Is it possible to apply it to two matrices row-wise?

Comment: It would be `lapply(seq_len(nrow(m1)), function(i) findInterval(m1[i,], m2[i,]))`

Comment: yeah, I used lapply, unfortunately there is no already defined method to work on matrices. Thanks